# Select query for tags in SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have very limited knowledge in Joins in sql. I have a table for selecting the tags. I'm using the many to many relationship.

My table structure is as follows:

`table links` 
`id, name, url`

`table tags`
`id, tag`

`table tagsmap`
`id, tagid, linkid`

Now, how can I select the tags corresponding to a particular link? I'm using Laravel.

I tried this:

```
DB::table('links')
            ->join('tags', 'link.id', '=', 'tags.link_id')
            ->join('tagmaps', 'link.id', '=', 'tagmpas.link_id')
            ->select('tags.tag')
            ->get();
```

Comment: What queries did you try already?

Comment: I downvoted you because your original question was not a question and you had no detail on what you had tried

Comment: Okay, I just added them now. (Hope you could have just commented instead of downvote)

Comment: Easier to click than type a response - but yes you did edit in a good way so will remove

Comment: But you commented as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `where()` clause to the SQL that [Michael posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27415038/658210) to return only the tags for the link you're interested in.

To get all the `tags` for a given `$url`:

```
DB::table('links')
        ->join('tagmaps', 'link.id', '=', 'tagmaps.linkid')
        ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'tagmaps.tagid')
        ->select('tags.tag', 'links.url', 'tags.id') // add more fields as needed
        ->where('url', $url)
        ->get();
```

And to get the `urls` for a given `$tag`:

```
DB::table('tags')
        ->join('tagmaps', 'tag.id', '=', 'tagmaps.tagid')
        ->join('links', 'links.id', '=', 'tagmaps.linkid')
        ->select('tags.tag', 'links.url', 'tags.id') // add more fields as needed
        ->where('tags.tag', $tag)
        ->get();
```

Better yet would be to set up Eloquent for your Link and Tag Models ([many to many](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)):

**Link Model:**

```
class Link extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'links';

    public function tags()
    {
        // you have to specify the table and the joining IDs here, as you 
        // are not using what Laravel would expect.
        // laravel expects the table to be called "map_tag" and the fields of 
        // that table to be link_id and tag_id, but it's configurable:
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tagsmap', 'linkid', 'tagid');
    }
}
```

**Tag Model:**

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tags';

}
```

And then you can access the tags for any given link through Eloquent:

```
 $tags = Link::where('url', $url)->first()->tags;
```

I've not tested it here, but that should work for you

Comment: Okay I will check this out. I'm in mobile now. Yes I have urls. The use case is where I want to display all the tags associated with a particular link.

Comment: @user1012181 I've not tested it, but it should work... I've reordered the joins to join the tables based on the tagmaps table, which wasn't being done before.  Good luck!

Comment: @user1012181, great!  glad to hear it!

Comment: What if I wanted to select a Link based on a Tag?

Comment: @user1012181 You'd just do the same thing in reverse!  Swapping Links for Tags in the appropriate places

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get your solution. Sorry if I sounds dumb :(

Comment: @user1012181 take a look at the update.. If it still doesn't make sense, it would be best to post a new question on the site.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just do `INNER JOIN` to solve that :

```
SELECT tags.tag as tag, links.name as links_name, links.url as url FROM tagsmap
  INNER JOIN tags ON tagsmap.tagid = tags.id
  INNER JOIN links ON tagsmap.linkid = links.id
WHERE tagsmap.id = "" //GIVE YOUR CONDITION HERE
```

Happy coding

#### UPDATE

```
DB::table('tagsmap')
        ->join('tags', 'tagsmap.tagid', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->join('links', 'tagsmap.linkid', '=', 'links.id')
        ->select('tags.tag,links.name,links.url')
        ->get();
```

I'm not well in LAVAREL but i'm trying to understand the logic. Edit my code as far as you know about LAVAREL

Comment: Could you try the same with the Laravel syntax I provided?

Comment: where's the problem ?

Comment: I'm getting all the tags from this.

Comment: @user1012181 There is no `where` clause in that query, so you'll get everything back as you're not filtering the results

Comment: @msturdy: could you help me with this one?